# An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException' occurred in Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll

Tags: c#

I wonder if someone can help me please?
I've picked up a project from a developer who is no longer here, and I need to rebuild one of his applications.

The application will build successfully, but if I try to run it I get the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll
>
> Additional information: Resolution of the dependency failed, type =
>   "App.MainForm", name = "(none)".

The program breaks on this line:

```
_mainForm = container.Resolve<MainForm>();
```

The entirety of the code I have is below:

```
    namespace Refunds
{
    internal class RefundApplicationContext : ApplicationContext
    {
        private TerritoryForm _territoryForm;
        private MainForm _mainForm;
        private IRefundProcessorConfig _config;

        public RefundApplicationContext()
        {
            using (IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer())
            using (ContainerControlledLifetimeManager manager = new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
            {
                container
                    .AddNewExtension<BuildTracking>()
                    .AddNewExtension<LogCreation>()
                    .RegisterType<MainForm>()
                    .RegisterType<IRefundProcessor, RefundProcessor>()
                    .RegisterType<IRefundCollection, RefundCollection>()
                    .RegisterType<ISepaValidation, SepaValidation>()
                    .RegisterType<IBankValidationConfig, BankValidationConfig>()
                    .RegisterType<IBankValidation, BankValidation>()
                    .RegisterType<IRefundProcessorConfig, RefundProcessorConfig>(manager)
                    .RegisterType<ISalesLedgerBrokerFacade, SalesLedgerBrokerFacade>()
                    .RegisterType<IPurchaseLedgerRestClientHelper, PurchaseLedgerRestClientHelper>()
                    .RegisterType<ISystemKeyRestClientHelper, SystemKeyRestClientHelper>()
                    .RegisterType<ISepaRestClientHelper, SepaRestClientHelper>()
                    .RegisterType<IPaymentHelper, PaymentHelper>()
                    .RegisterType<IPdfDocument, PdfDocument>()
                    .RegisterType<IStringCipher, StringCipher>()
                    .RegisterType<IRefundFactory, RefundFactory>()
                    .RegisterType<IFileHelperEngine<Refunds.Implementation.Csv.Refund>, FileHelperEngine<Refunds.Implementation.Csv.Refund>>(new InjectionConstructor())
                    .RegisterType<IDirectDebitBusinessServiceFacade, DirectDebitBusinessServiceFacade>();

                _territoryForm = container.Resolve<TerritoryForm>();
                _mainForm = container.Resolve<MainForm>();
                _config = container.Resolve<IRefundProcessorConfig>();
            }


            _territoryForm.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(_territoryForm_FormClosed);
            _mainForm.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(_mainForm_FormClosed);

            _territoryForm.Show();

            _mainForm.Show();
        }

        private void _territoryForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_territoryForm.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                _config.Territory = _territoryForm.Territory;

                _mainForm.Show();
            }
            else
                ExitThread();
        }

        private void _mainForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            ExitThread();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just guessing, but does MainForm() has an empty constructor?

Comment: Spitballing at code we cannot see, a "MainForm" is special since there should only ever be one instance of it.  The kind of thing you enforce by making the constructor private.

Comment: I've added all of the code to the post so you can see everything. I hope this helps.

Comment: Try:  _mainForm = container.Resolve<MainForm>();